# Prove the formula for the sum of consecutive cubes

Tags: summation, induction

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{4}$$

Please help

Comment: what have u tried and where r u stuck

Comment: @Guest For the future: you can flag the question, choosing   "it is a duplicate" reason, to make other users aware of the duplicate.

Comment: @Behaviour Thanks, I thought only high-power users could flag.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$, it holds; Suppose that $n=m$, the equality also holds, i.e., $$\sum_{k=1}^mk^3=\frac{m^2(m+1)^2}{4}.$$

Now $$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}k^3=\frac{m^2(m+1)^2}{4}+(m+1)^3=\frac{(m+1)^2(m+2)^2}{4}.$$

Comment: The last equality hides the algebra which is the essence of the proof. I think it should be expanded showing all the steps.