# Prove the exact formula of $\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

When counting FLOPS, one must often compute
certain sums.

Prove the exact formula

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

I have used the approximation  $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\approx\int_{1}^{n}f(k)dk$ to find that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3= \frac{n^4}{4} + LOT$$ Lot stands for lower order terms

how do I go from here to calculate the exact number of flops for  $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3$$

Comment: Surely you mean $n^4/4 + LOT$.

Comment: There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but I think the most straightforward is probably going to be to use induction

Comment: See the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058425/prove-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-consecutive-cubes

Comment: i do mean $n^4/4$ i will correct that

Comment: For more general power sums, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667258/how-is-faulhabers-formula-derived) or [this excellent Mathologer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw1kRz83Fj0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that

$$
\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} + (n+1)^3 = \frac{[n^2 + 4(n+1)](n+1)^2}{4} = \frac{(n+2)^2(n+1)^2}{4}
$$

Then proceed by induction.

Comment: Much more elegant than my approach, I just expanded everything out and then checked that the polynomials matched. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a fan of induction, you can solve problems like these using something that's similar to the derivative for sums. If you have seen derivatives before, you may know the power rule, which shows that $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = \lim_ {h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h} = nx^{n-1}$. The important aspect of this is that the highest power decreases by 1 each time we apply the derivative. The same thing happens with sums. In particular  $$\frac{(x+1)^n-x^n}{1} =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}x^k = nx^{n-1}+LOT\ $$

If I take the 'derivative' of the sum enough times, the LOT will go away.

Here is how to work out this method for your sum

**Derivative 1**
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^3 - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^3 = n^3$$
**Derivative 2**
$$n^3-(n-1)^3=3n^2 + LOT$$
**Derivative 3**
$$3n^2 + LOT - (3(n-1)^2 + LOT) = 6n+LOT$$
**Derivative 4**
$$6n+LOT-(6(n-1)+LOT) = 6$$
Since we know that the 4th derivative is 6, then the first term in our polynomial is $\frac{6}{4!}$ (we divide by 4! to counteract the fact that each derivative multiplies by n, so we have multiplied by 4*3*2*1).
So, we get rid of the 4th power term and apply this process again.

**Derivative 1**
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^3-\left(\frac{n^4}{4}\right) - \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^3- \left(\frac{(n-1)^4}{4}\right)\right) = n^3 - \frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{(n-1)^4}{4} = \frac{6n^2}{4} + LOT$$
From here, we can immediately skip to the 3rd derivative by ignoring the LOT, and get that the 3rd derivative is 3.
So, we now have $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 = \frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{n^3}{2} +LOT$$
Applying this one final time would yield
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 = \frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{n^3}{2} +\frac{n^2}{4}$$

Obviously, this process takes a lot more work than induction, and if you already know what formula the sum should turn into, use induction instead. I only include this method because this is something that is quite straightforward to code, and so if you do decide to code this you can get a solution to *any* FLOPS question which asks you to simplify a sum.

Comment: This is a really good answer but I think I will follow the proof by induction.